# Activity is not responding

Tags: android, android-activity

my application was working fine 
suddenly its stopped working and whenever i am trying to run it it says this in the error log , kindly fill in your experience

i am using http post client to get response from a web service , which till now was working fine , it has some sudden effect , initially i thought my bad internet connction is affecting but it seems to linger in the good net connection also

```
10-18 19:06:21.554: D/AndroidRuntime(311): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-18 19:06:21.554: D/AndroidRuntime(311): CheckJNI is ON
10-18 19:06:21.653: D/AndroidRuntime(311): --- registering native functions ---
10-18 19:06:22.073: D/AndroidRuntime(311): Shutting down VM
10-18 19:06:22.073: D/dalvikvm(311): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-18 19:06:22.083: I/AndroidRuntime(311): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-18 19:06:22.423: D/AndroidRuntime(319): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-18 19:06:22.423: D/AndroidRuntime(319): CheckJNI is ON
10-18 19:06:22.523: D/AndroidRuntime(319): --- registering native functions ---
10-18 19:06:22.943: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.gt_google_svn/.Auth }
10-18 19:06:22.953: D/AndroidRuntime(319): Shutting down VM
10-18 19:06:22.953: D/dalvikvm(319): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-18 19:06:22.963: I/AndroidRuntime(319): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-18 19:06:44.220: W/WindowManager(58): Key dispatching timed out sending to com.gt_google_svn/com.gt_google_svn.Auth
10-18 19:06:44.220: W/WindowManager(58): Previous dispatch state: null
10-18 19:06:44.224: W/WindowManager(58): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{45080188 com.gt_google_svn/com.gt_google_svn.Auth paused=false} @ 1350567404223 lw=Window{45080188 com.gt_google_svn/com.gt_google_svn.Auth paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@4500e0f8 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{45080188 com.gt_google_svn/com.gt_google_svn.Auth paused=false}}}
10-18 19:06:44.244: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 301 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.244: I/dalvikvm(301): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.284: I/dalvikvm(301): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.284: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 58 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.284: I/dalvikvm(58): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.324: I/dalvikvm(58): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.324: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 124 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.324: I/dalvikvm(124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.334: I/dalvikvm(124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.334: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 285 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.334: I/dalvikvm(285): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.345: I/dalvikvm(285): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.345: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 256 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.345: I/dalvikvm(256): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.354: I/dalvikvm(256): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.354: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 195 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.354: I/dalvikvm(195): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.364: I/dalvikvm(195): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.364: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 201 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.364: I/dalvikvm(201): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.374: I/dalvikvm(201): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.374: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 253 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.374: I/dalvikvm(253): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.384: I/dalvikvm(253): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.384: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 108 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.384: I/dalvikvm(108): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.404: I/dalvikvm(108): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.404: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 112 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.404: I/dalvikvm(112): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.424: I/dalvikvm(112): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.424: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 207 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.424: I/dalvikvm(207): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.434: I/dalvikvm(207): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.434: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 160 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.434: I/dalvikvm(160): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.464: I/dalvikvm(160): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.464: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 175 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.464: I/dalvikvm(175): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.474: I/dalvikvm(175): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.474: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 216 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.484: I/dalvikvm(216): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.494: I/dalvikvm(216): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.494: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 269 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.494: I/dalvikvm(269): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.504: I/dalvikvm(269): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.504: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 232 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.504: I/dalvikvm(232): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.515: I/dalvikvm(232): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.515: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 144 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.515: I/dalvikvm(144): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.534: I/dalvikvm(144): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.534: I/Process(58): Sending signal. PID: 125 SIG: 3
10-18 19:06:44.534: I/dalvikvm(125): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-18 19:06:44.544: I/dalvikvm(125): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58): ANR in com.gt_google_svn (com.gt_google_svn/.Auth)
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58): Load: 0.59 / 0.48 / 0.2
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58): CPU usage from 44545ms to 18ms ago:
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   system_server: 2% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 119 minor 4 major
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   adbd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 28 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 156 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   m.gt_google_svn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 27 minor 6 major
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 146 minor 1 major
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   putmethod.latin: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 172 minor 1 major
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 39 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 109 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 77 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 76 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   .quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 323 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 268 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 92 minor 1 major
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 78 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   s:FriendService: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 77 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   m.android.email: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 98 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58):   com.svox.pico: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor
10-18 19:06:44.574: E/ActivityManager(58): TOTAL: 8% = 5% user + 2% kernel + 0% softirq
10-18 19:06:44.604: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-18 19:06:44.624: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-18 19:06:44.624: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
10-18 19:06:44.634: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-18 19:06:44.734: W/KeyCharacterMap(58): No keyboard for id 0
10-18 19:06:44.734: W/KeyCharacterMap(58): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-18 19:06:45.014: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x3250d0:0x32518c] in 326428 ns
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AsyncTask and take off your long running task from your UI thread. Read the posts below for more concrete information

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html